# Python Fabric error

Tags: python, django, deployment, fabric

I'm running fabric (Django deployment to apache) and everything seems to work fine until I get to the task for installing the site:

```
def install_site():
    "Add the virtualhost file to apache"
    require('release', provided_by=[deploy, setup])
    sudo('cd %(path)/releases/%(release)/%(release); cp %(project_name)/%(virtualhost_path)/%(project_domain) /etc/apache2/sites-available/%(project_domain)s')
    sudo('cd /etc/apache2/sites-available; a2ensite %(project_domain)')
```

I keep getting this error:

```
[173.203.124.16] sudo: cd %(path)/releases/%(release)/%(release);
[173.203.124.16] err: /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token
`('
[173.203.124.16] err: /bin/bash: -c: line 0: `cd %(path)/releases/%(release)/%(r
elease);'

Warning: sudo() encountered an error (return code 2) while executing 'cd %(path)
/releases/%(release)/%(release);'
```

I've gone through the fabfile.py over and over and I can't see why the error is coming...any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def install_site():
    "Add the virtualhost file to apache"
    require('release', provided_by=[deploy, setup])

    with cd('%(path)s/releases/%(release)s/%(release)s' % env):
        sudo('cp %(project_name)s/%(virtualhost_path)s/%(project_domain)s '
                 '/etc/apache2/sites-available/%(project_domain)s' % env)
    with cd('/etc/apache2/sites-available'):
         sudo('a2ensite %(project_domain)s' % env)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using the [cd context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/api/core/context_managers.html?#fabric.context_managers.cd). You're probably also having problems with your [string interpolation](http://zackola.com/blog/2008/06/30/python-string-interpolation/).

```
def install_site():
    # Add the virtualhost file to apache
    require('release', provided_by=[deploy, setup])

    with cd('%s/releases/%s/%s' % (path, release, release)):
        sudo('cp %s/%s/%s /etc/apache2/sites-available/%s' % (project_name, virtualhost_path, project_domain, project_domain))

    with cd('/etc/apache2/sites-available'):
        sudo('a2ensite %s' % project_domain)
```

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed, noticing something with the "hg archive .." command, it zips/tars the repo 2 levels deep

```
local('hg archive --type=tgz %(release)s.tar.gz' % {'release': env.release})
```

results in 20100418105144.tar.gz which when u open is structured like this:

> 20100418105144.tar.gz
>       /20100418105144
>       /repo